# Python Variable Strange Syntax Error

Tags: python, string, variables

My python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree

tree = ETree.ElementTree(file="CountryData.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

textfile = open("Output.txt", "w")


print("Population densities:")

for i in root:
    density = str(float((i.attrib["areaInSqKm"])/float(i.attrib["population"]))
    n = (i.get("countryName"))
    b = n + ": " + density + "people/km2 \n"
    textfile.write(b)

textfile.close()
```

is giving me the following error:

```
      File "G:\CountryData.py", line 13
         n = i.get("countryName"))
         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried multiple methods and other ways of writing it, but I have no Idea how to fix this. Doeas anybody see My error?

ps, it worked fine before I added the bit about density of population

Comment: You're missing a `)` in line 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss 1 character :)

```
density = str(float((i.attrib["areaInSqKm"])/float(i.attrib["population"]))

density = str(float((i.attrib["areaInSqKm"])/float(i.attrib["population"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing paren in this line:

```
str(float((i.attrib["areaInSqKm"])/float(i.attrib["population"]))
```

It should be:

```
str(float((i.attrib["areaInSqKm"])/float(i.attrib["population"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line instead (you have a missing right-paren):

```
density = str(float((i.attrib["areaInSqKm"])/float(i.attrib["population"])))
```